# CSV to DB ETL with MuleSoft / DataWeave, 3:1 relationship

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I am working on a CSV to DB ETL.  I want to use a Mule application and DataWeave. If there were a 1:1 relationship between CSV rows and table rows, this would be trivial. However, for this use case, there is a 3:1 relationship.

An example of the input CSV is something like this:
"id", "type", "val1", "val2", "val3"
1, A, 5,,,
2, B,, 12,
3, C,,, "ABC"
That is, every row has certain columns populated, like "id" and "type".  However, the values in some rows depend on the value in another column (in this case "type"). In this example, if type is A, then val1 has a value, if B, then val2 does, C then val3 does.

DataWeave is not great at saying "Read these next three rows" and then tangling with the data.  So, what I'm currently thinking is that I'll have three Processors (operations) with File Read, get the 3 rows into variable, then combine them into a record for the database. However, what drives the getting of the three rows?  The code needs something that reads until the end of the file. But there is no flow, or for that matter DW, that loops until a generic boolean is true/false like we have in imperative languages.  The work-around is to use recursive calls with an escape hatch. Maybe I'll try combining a "lookup" to call the code to set the variables and then have that lookup call nested in a recursive function.

Anyone else run into a similar problem and solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to group the lines in groups of 3 that can easily be done with the [divideBy() function of the Arrays module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-arrays-functions-divideby).

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
---
payload divideBy 3
```

Each element of the output array will be an array of 3 items of the input array, ie lines in the case of CSV.

You may need to test performance for big CSV files. I'm not sure streaming is possible, depending on if divideBy() uses indexed access or not.